# Linear interpolation within groups

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a multi-index dataframe `df` with one column `A`. I would like to create a new column `B` where I assign the values `m` (e.g. 0) and `M` (e.g. 1) to the lowest and highest values within each group of column `A`, while linearly interpolating all values between.

As an example, consider the following `df`.  I would like to do the interpolation for every `X` group

```
                     A 
X      Y                              
bar   one    -0.007381 
      two    -1.219794 
baz   one     0.145578 
      two    -0.249321 
      three  -0.249321 
      four    0.21     
foo   one    -1.046479 
      two     1.314373 
qux   one     0.716789 
      two     0.385795
```

I believe I can do this with combination of `aggregate` and `transform` in Pandas, but am not sure how.

Comment: How do you determine ordering? Based on the ordinal words in `Y`, alphabetically on `Y`, or by the ordering of the values in `A`? Once you've answered that: do you want simple quantiles (e.g. 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 for a group with three members) or an affine re-scaling of the values of `Y` to [m,M]?

Comment: Thanks @RamanShah Doing it with quantiles would be **great**. I am not sure I understand your ordering question. Within each `X` group, there are several rows (`A` entries). What I want is to assign a number in a new column `B` in the range `m-M` to each row based on the quantiles they belong to within their `X` level. This number should be linearly interpolated. E.g. bottom `10%` gets `m`, next `10%` gets `10%(M-m) + m`, etc.

Comment: The first example in the [transform docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) is relevant very close to what you want.

Comment: I see. My ordering question is follows: let's take `baz`, say. Do you want to assign the quantiles based on the ordering `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`? Or alphabetically on `Y` - `four`, `one`, `three`, `two`? Or in increasing order of `A` - `three`, `two`, `one`, `four` (depending on tie-breaking rules)?

Answer (score 2):

It think it may be better if you use `groupby` rather than `mutliIndex`:
Data:

```
X      Y    A                          
bar   one    -0.007381 
bar   two    -1.219794 
baz   one     0.145578 
baz   two    -0.249321 
baz   three  -0.249321 
baz   four    0.21     
foo   one    -1.046479 
foo   two     1.314373 
qux   one     0.716789 
qux   two     0.385795
```

And:

```
In [47]:

df['new']=df.groupby(df.X).transform(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / x.ptp()).A
print df
     X      Y         A       new
0  bar    one -0.007381  1.000000
1  bar    two -1.219794  0.000000
2  baz    one  0.145578  0.859745
3  baz    two -0.249321  0.000000
4  baz  three -0.249321  0.000000
5  baz   four  0.210000  1.000000
6  foo    one -1.046479  0.000000
7  foo    two  1.314373  1.000000
8  qux    one  0.716789  1.000000
9  qux    two  0.385795  0.000000

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```